# Access 2013 Can't display image from attachment when first opening the database

Tags: image, runtime-error, attachment, ms-access-2013

Having searched vigorously for an answer without result and given the strangeness of the issue, I feel posting a new question  is the only hope for getting this resolved.

I have a table with products (ProductName and ProductImage) The image is an attachment field.

I have a search Form (unbound) with a listbox that displays a list of these products (column 1=ID, column 2=Productname, column3=ProductImage)

I have an image control that displays the image of the product with the following code in the ON LOAD event of the form and the AFTER UPDATE event of the listbox.

Me.imgProduct.Picture = Me.lstProduct.Column(3)

And it works, the image gets displayed when the form is loaded and when the selection is changed... At least until I close and reopen the database.

When I freshly open the database and open the form, I get the following error: Runtime-error 2220 Microsoft Access can't open the file product1.png

When I add a random new attachment to a new attachment FIELD or OLE object to ANY table, it works again without flaw.

Please, can somebody explain what's happening here? Is it to do with directory permissions or something? How to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to abandon attachment field and am working with links to the images instead.

Question isn't solved, but the problem is.